# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Helper_Cookie' not found magento

Tags: magento, themes

I created a theme on my own magento website, and uploaded it to another magento website, but when i go to the frontend of that website i get this

Fatal error: Class \\’Mage_Core_Helper_Cookie\\’ not found in /home/winterwa/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 516

I searched for a solution and tried this one described in this topic: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280318/#t401019

(cookie.php in app/code/core/mage/core/helper) but it didn\\’t help a thing.

Any suggestions/solutions for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the two different Magento installs are running different versions of Magento. The file in question is only added to Magento in version 1.7. I can only assume that you have taken a fresh install of 1.7 and based your theme off of the default / base theme for this. Therefore when the theme gets added to an older version of Magento it is trying to load Blocks / Templates that you haven't overloaded and that just don't exist in the base template.

Unfortunately this won't be the easiest thing to fix. You will need to go through the layout/template files, removing references that add blocks or use helpers that don't exist for the current version of magento. For the issue you mention, you should be able to find by searching for helper('cookie') in your template files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is the problem indeed, i will modify my files. Thanks again!